# HighCharts JS Column Graph yAxis Going Above Ceiling Value

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

Working on building a highcharts element that displays last 20 games "Headshot%" in a Column Bar Graph.

The issue i'm running into, is despite setting my yAxis value range `floor: 0, ceiling: 100,` my graphs top tick is 120%.

If I lower my ceiling amount to 90> then it will accurately set the ceiling to the correct value.

NOTE: I have tested to see if my series values going over 100 in an attempt to create zones was causing the  issue, although it appears to have no effect.

JSFIDDLE LINK: https://jsfiddle.net/Lukeolafp/vt49zhdx/

---

Code (Incase JSFiddle Fork Stops working)

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
          type: 'column',
          backgroundColor: '#2A2A2A',
      },

      title: false,

      subtitle: false,

      xAxis: {
          categories: ['Game 1', 'Game 2', 'Game 3','Game 4', 'Game 5', 'Game 6','Game 7', 'Game 8', 'Game 9','Game 10',
                      'Game 11', 'Game 12', 'Game 13','Game 14', 'Game 15', 'Game 16','Game 17', 'Game 18', 'Game 19','Game 20'
                    ],
          labels: {
            enabled: false
          }
          
      },
      yAxis: {
        floor: 0,
        ceiling: 100,
        tickAmount: 4,
        title: {
          text: null
        },
        labels: {
          formatter: function() {
          return this.value + ' %';
          },
          style: {
          fontSize: 10,
          color: '#FFF',
          fontFamily: 'Helvetica Neue',
          fontWeight: 'regular'
          },
        },
      },

      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointWidth: 9,
            borderRadius: 3,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
      },

      series: [{
          name: 'Headshot %',
          showInLegend: false,
          data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 99, 100, 34, 13, 35, 15, 12, 19, 11, 13, 22],
          zones: [{
            value: 15,
            color: '#ffffff'
          },{
            value: 30,
            color: '#A2F8B5',
          },{
            value: 45,
            color: '#42DC64',
          }, {
            value: 90,
            color: '#00B828',
          },{
            value: 100,
            color: {
              linearGradient: { x1: 0, x2: 0, y1: 0, y2: 1 },
              stops: [
                  [0, '#C9A44B'], // start
                  [0.5, '#F7E991'], // middle
                  [1, '#C9A44B'] // end
              ]
            }
          },{
            value: 101,
            color: '#FF78F2'
          }]
      }]
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>HTML CSS JS ISOLATE TEST ENVIROMENT</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="sidePanelHeadshotHighChart" id="container"></div>

        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="heatmap.js-master/build/heatmap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
    

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #505050;
}

.sidePanelHeadshotHighChart {
  height: 64px;
  width: 283px;
  /* height: 400px;
  width: 100%; */
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you've set `tickAmount: 4` property and the interval for ticks can not be evenly calculated. Use `tickPositions` instead:

```
yAxis: {
  tickPositions: [0, 33.33, 66.66, 100],
  ...
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ykbhwrfs/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickAmount

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions

Answer (score 0):

The High Charts js docs show `min` and `max` instead of `floor` and `ceiling`.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Appreciate the quick response,

although I just tried it, didn't fix the problem.

It appears to work in the same way as the ceiling. If I set the Max at 90> then it correctly sets the Y axis, but anything higher than 90 and it automatically defaults to 120%

Comment: Bummer, the above on their website was changing the range of the charts for me. Hope you're able to figure it out